# Backpropagation and Gradient Descent: Questions on math behind it

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIeHLnjs5U8) video which goes over backpropagation calculus and read the Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation) on it.  This is my understanding of the equations for the algorithm.  I have questions regarding the equations and backpropagation inline in **bold font with ?**.

### Definitions:

$C_t$ is the cost or loss function for example $t$, $\mathbf x$ is the input vector of features, $\mathbf y$ is the target output, $L$ is the number of layers, $a$ is the activation function, $z$ is the raw activation, $w_{jk}^{(l)}$ is the weights between layer $l - 1$ and $l$, where $k$ is the index of the neuron in layer $l - 1$, $j$ is the index of the neuron in the layer $l$.  $\sigma$ is the sigmoid function. $a_j^l$ is activation of $j$-th node in layer $l$.  $C_t(\mathbf y, \mathbf a^L) = \langle (\textbf a^L - \textbf y)^2, \textbf 1 \rangle$.

The overall network for one input/output pair can be described as:
$$C_t(\mathbf y, g(\mathbf x)), g(\mathbf x) := a^L(W^L a^{L-1}(W^{L-1} \cdots a^1(W^1 \mathbf x)\cdots)), $$

- Model training phase: $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ are fixed, while $w_{jk}^l$ vary.
- Model evaluation phase: $w_{jk}^l$ and $\mathbf y$ are fixed, while $\mathbf x$ varies.

The following equations are from the video.

$$a_j^{(0)} = \mathbf x$$
$$C_t = \sum_{j=0}^{n_L - 1} (a_j^{(L)} - y_j)^2 = \langle (\textbf a^{(L)} - \textbf y)^2, \textbf 1 \rangle$$
$$a_j^{(L)} = \sigma(z_j^{(L)}), z_j^{(L)} = \sum_{k=0}^{n_L - 1} (w_{jk}^{(L)} a_k^{(L-1)}) + b_j^{(L)}$$

$$\frac {\partial C_t} {\partial w_{jk}^{(L)}} = \frac {\partial z_j^{(L)}} {\partial w_{jk}^{(L)}} \frac {\partial a_j^{(L)}} {\partial z_j^{(L)}} \frac {\partial C_t} {\partial a_j^{(L)}} = a_k^{(L-1)} \sigma '(z_j^{(L)}) 2(a_j^{(L)} - y_j)$$

$$\frac {\partial z_j^{(L)}} {\partial w_{jk}^{(L)}} = a_k^{(L-1)}, \frac {\partial a_j^{(L)}} {\partial z_j^{(L)}} = \sigma '(z_j^{(L)}), \frac {\partial C_t} {\partial a_j^{(L)}} = 2(a_j^{(L)} - y_j)$$

$$\frac {\partial C_t} {\partial b_{j}^{(L)}} = \frac {\partial z_j^{(L)}} {\partial b_j^{(L)}} \frac {\partial a_j^{(L)}} {\partial z_j^{(L)}} \frac {\partial C_t} {\partial a_j^{(L)}} = 1 \sigma '(z_j^{(L)}) 2(a_j^{(L)} - y_j)$$

$$\frac {\partial C_t} {\partial a_k^{(L-1)}} = \sum_{j=0}^{n_L - 1} \frac {\partial z_j^{(L)}} {\partial a_k^{(L-1)}} \frac {\partial a_j^{(L)}} {\partial z_j^{(L)}} \frac {\partial C_t} {\partial a_j^{(L)}} = \sum_{j=0}^{n_L - 1} w_{jk}^{(L)} \sigma '(z_j^{(L)}) 2(a_j^{(L)} - y_j)$$

$$\frac {\partial z_j^{L}} {\partial a_j^{(L-1)}} = w_{jk}^{(L)}$$

Average over all training examples:

$$ \frac {\partial C} {\partial w_{jk}^{(L)}} = \frac {1} {n} \sum_{t=0}^{n-1} \frac {\partial C_t} {\partial w_{jk}^{(L)}}$$

$$\frac {\partial C}{\partial b_j^{(L)}} = \frac {1} {n} \sum_{t=0}^{n-1} \frac {\partial C_t} {\partial b_{j}^{(L)}}$$

**QUESTION: I tried to put this together from the video.  Is this appropriate notation for definition the gradient of the cost function given all weights and biases?**

$$C \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R, \nabla C \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$$
$$\nabla C = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac {\partial C} {\partial w_{00}^{(1)}} \cr
\frac {\partial C} {\partial b_{0}^{(1)}} \cr
\vdots \cr
\frac {\partial C} {\partial w_{MN}^{(L)}} \cr
\frac {\partial C} {\partial b_{M}^{(L)}} \cr
\end{bmatrix} $$

The gradient descent algorithm:
$$\mathbf p_{n+1}=\mathbf p_n - \gamma \nabla C(\mathbf p_n), n \ge 0$$
$$\gamma \in \mathbb R_{+}$$

If the following is the directional derivative, then $\min_{\vec x=\vec 1} \nabla_{\vec x} C(\mathbf {\vec p})$ is a goal, which would minimize the total cost.

Where:

$$a^{(L)} = \sigma(z^{(L)}), z^{(L)} = W^{(L)} a^{(L-1)} + b^{(L)}, a^{(0)} = \mathbf x$$

$$W^{(L)} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
w_{0,0}^{(L)} & w_{0,1}^{(L)} & \dots & w_{0,n}^{(L)} \cr
w_{1,0}^{(L)} & w_{1,1}^{(L)} & \dots & w_{1,n}^{(L)} \cr
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \cr
w_{k,0}^{(L)} & w_{k,1}^{(L)} & \dots & w_{k,n}^{(L)}
\end{bmatrix}
,
a^{(L)} =
\begin{bmatrix}
a_0^{(L)} \cr
a_1^{(L)} \cr
\vdots \cr
a_n^{(L)}
\end{bmatrix}
,
b^{(L)} =
\begin{bmatrix}
b_0^{(L)} \cr
b_1^{(L)} \cr
\vdots \cr
b_n^{(L)}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

### BACKPROPAGATION

From Wikipedia, I inferred the following: Computing the above $\frac {\partial C_x} {\partial w_{jk}^{(L)}}$ and $\frac {\partial C_x} {\partial b_{j}^{(L)}}$ using the chain rule is inefficient.  Backpropagation computes $\nabla C$ more efficiently by computing the gradient of weighted input $\nabla_{W^l} a^{(l)} = \delta^l$ from $l = L$ (back/output) to $l = 0$ (front/input), which avoids duplicate calculations of both prior pd equations.  It also avoids unnecessary computation of $\frac {\partial z^l_j}{\partial w^l_{jk}}$.

$$\nabla_{W^l} a^{(l)} = \delta^l = (a^l)' \circ (W^{l+1})^T\cdot(a^{l+1})' \circ \cdots \circ (W^{L-1})^T \cdot (a^{L-1})' \circ (W^L)^T \cdot (a^L)' \circ \nabla_{a^L} C$$
$$\nabla_{W^l} C = \delta^l(a^{l-1})^T$$
$$\delta^{l-1} := (a^{l-1})' \circ (W^l)^T \cdot \delta^l$$

Where:
$$a^{(L)} = \sigma(z^{(L)}), z^{(L)} = (w^{(L)} a^{(L-1)}) + b^{(L)}$$

Total derivative given by:
$$df_a = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a) \cdot dx_i$$

$$\frac{d C}{\partial x}= \frac{d C}{d a^L}\cdot \frac{d a^L}{d z^L} \cdot \frac{d z^L}{d a^{L-1}} \cdot \frac{d a^{L-1}}{d z^{L-1}}\cdot \frac{d z^{L-1}}{d a^{L-2}} \cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{d a^1}{d z^1} \cdot \frac{\partial z^1}{\partial x}$$

or equivalently expanded in functional form:
$$
\nabla_x C = (W^1)^T \cdot (a^1)' \circ \ldots \circ (W^{L-1})^T \cdot (a^{L-1})' \circ (W^L)^T \cdot (a^L)' \circ \nabla_{a^L} C
$$

Where $\nabla_{a^L} C$ and $\nabla_x C$ are the partial derivatives of $C$ with respect to $a^L$ and $x$.

For comparison if we computed $\nabla_{w^L} C$ forward the steps would be the following with repeated computations:
$$
\begin{align}
\delta^1 &= (f^1)' \circ (W^2)^T \cdot (f^2)' \circ \cdots \circ (W^{L-1})^T \cdot (f^{L-1})' \circ (W^L)^T \cdot (f^L)' \circ \nabla_{a^L} C\\
\delta^2 &= (f^2)' \circ \cdots \circ (W^{L-1})^T \cdot (f^{L-1})' \circ (W^L)^T \cdot (f^L)' \circ \nabla_{a^L} C\\
&\vdots\\
\delta^{L-1} &= (f^{L-1})' \circ (W^L)^T \cdot (f^L)' \circ \nabla_{a^L} C\\
\delta^L &= (f^L)' \circ \nabla_{a^L} C,
\end{align}
$$

Computing these values in reverse, avoids the repeated computations.

Comment: You may be interested in [Michael Nielsen's textbook](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html), which guides you through the equations of backpropagation a bit more.

Comment: There are some smaller inconsistencies in your notion (which is not too uncommon, if things come together from different sources). Some parts looks a bit uncommon to me, but that might just be a question of taste. I would hesitate to comment on everything you have posted. So which parts are you especially interested in?